# Find all members without a role and send a message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to place an order that searches for all members who do not have a role and sends them a DM, can you help me?

So far I have managed to find the users but they all show up because everyone to everyone, I don't know what to do after that.

```
const Role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "@everyone");
    const members = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.roles.cache.find(role => role == Role))
```

Comment: There's alot of room for API spam here. You would need to fetch all the members, then in the end DM them all, which would create alot of API calls

Answer (score 0):

The program you are trying to execute will call the discord API a lot of times, thus resulting in being rate limited. I suggest you make another role for the order you are trying to place and give all of the members that role and proceed with your code